# VBA to Lock/Unlock each row based on Data list for table

Tags: excel, vba, protected

I need a little guidance. I do not want to use Data Validation to restrict data entry in the cells as the warnings for accidentally typing will decrease productivity. I want the user to be able to select from the list in the Table column C and it lock the unnecessary cells so they can quickly tab over the locked cells. I will need the code to function for each line in my table. I used my target range as ActiveSheet.ListObjects so it will also continue to work with the sheet is copied for the next month. I have also tried C3:C (my data does begin on line 3) as the target range and still cannot get it to work.

My drop box in the Column C (Table Column Header is Payment Type) has 3 possibilities 
PDPM- should lock AE:AJ in each row if selected
RUGs IV- should lock AA:AD in each row
Levels- should lock AA:AJ

So frustrated!

Data Validation- not doing what I want
Target C3:C
Multiple codes found on here haha

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range(ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Name & "[[#All],[Payment Type]]")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="Protection"
    Select Case Target.Value
        Case "PDPM"
            Range("AE" & Target.Row & ":AJ" & Target.Row).Locked = True
        Case "RUGs IV"
            Range("AA" & Target.Row & ":AD" & Target.Row).Locked = True
        Case "Levels"
            Range("AA" & Target.Row & ":AJ" & Target.Row).Locked = True
        Case Else
            Range("AA" & Target.Row & ":AJ" & Target.Row).Locked = False
    End Select
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="Protection"
End Sub
```

Does nothing! No errors

Answer (score 1):

You wrote: "the warnings for accidentally typing will decrease productivity". So, I'm thinking that maybe the solution for you would be simply to disabled the validation error message by **unchecking** the checkbox in the following window:

[image: Data Validation Window]

If that's not enough to solve your problem, feel free to write a comment to this answer and I'll edit my answer if needed.

**EDIT:**

From comments:

- Try using F8 to debug your code line by line and see if the code is executing correctly?
- Regarding running the code only when the Target is in column C, you could add: `If Target.Column = 3 then` at the start of your code.

Comment: I now see I can disable the warning, but it still does not allow the user to tab over the areas that do not need to be filled in like they can with a locked cell

Comment: @PokeCoder : Have you tried using F8 to debug your code line by line and see if the code is executing correctly?

Comment: Finally got it. Was hoping to find a way to only trigger when column C is changed. Slows my worksheet down quite a bit

Comment: @PokeCoder - Awesome. Regarding running the code only when the Target is in column C, you could add: `If Target.Column = 3 then` at the start of your code.

Comment: That worked liked a charm, the sheet is much faster now!

Comment: @PokeCoder - Great! If this answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it by [clicking the check mark beside it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/372533). This is not an obligation, but it indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Comment: @PokeCoder, you should add the solution to your answer if you want it to be marked. Comments are not for answers. A marked answer should contain the real solution, so it helps people who search with a similar problem, without them having to go through all the comments as well.